# How can I avoid streaks from a paint sprayer?

Tags: paint, cabinets

I'm in the process of painting my kitchen cupboards. (I know, it's a sin to paint over wood, but it was quicker than stripping the stain). I used a foam roller for the cabinet and decided to spray the doors. Here's [the gun I was using](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006FRPJ) (neat little thing).

I was a bit surprised to see "light streaks" from the spray gun. See the image below.

[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view.*</sup>

Any ideas what is causing this? Any ideas on how to avoid it? I was just going to go over the face with a paint roller, but that kinda defeats the purpose of spraying.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the streaks aren't from the roller you used on the first coat?

Comment: I didn't use a roller on any coat--all sprayed. (The roller was for the cabinet, not the doors. I'll edit my question to make it less confusing).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to make out what's going on from the picture but the usual culprit when spraying is either an imperfection in your fan(spray pattern) or problems with your prep work. Take your sprayer and shoot a short burst at a smooth surface (a piece of cardboard works) If the pattern shows any obvious abnormalities, it's either not enough air pressure or a defect in the tip itself (or sometimes just a goober of finish clinging to the tip). A pattern like this
[image]

is classic low pressure. A bunged tip will look less symmetrical but the streaks left in the finish can look very similar.

If the fan looks good and the problem doesn't show up on test pieces, take a hard look at the surface of your cabinets. They might need a little more scuff sanding or a good cleaning with TSP to get the grease off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The sprayer that I use gives a circle pattern, which I think is by design. So the glossy areas (I think) are where the center of the circle was on the second coat. Do I just need to overlap more?

Comment: Yeah you may need to do a few coats to smooth it out. Try doing  your second coat side to side, then a final coat up and down to disguise the pattern and you should be good.